# ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host under Git bash

Tags: git, ssh

I work at win7 and set up git server with sshd.
I `git --bare init myapp.git`, and clone `ssh://git@localhost/home/git/myapp.git` in **Cywgin** correctly. But I need config git of **Cygwin** again, I want to git clone in **Git Bash**. I run `git clone ssh://git@localhost/home/git/myapp.git` and get following message

```
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

then I run `ssh -vvv git@localhost` in **Git Bash** and get message

```
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to localhost [127.0.0.1] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /c/Users/MoreFreeze/.ssh/identity type -1
debug3: Not a RSA1 key file /c/Users/MoreFreeze/.ssh/id_rsa.
debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type '-----BEGIN'
debug3: key_read: missing keytype
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace 
// above it repeats 24 times
debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type '-----END'
debug3: key_read: missing keytype
debug1: identity file /c/Users/MoreFreeze/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/MoreFreeze/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

it seems my private keys has wrong format? And I find that there are exactly 25 line in private keys without `BEGIN` and `END`.
I'm confused why it said NOT RSA1 key, I totally ensure it is RSA 2 key.

Any advises are welcome.
btw, I have read first 3 pages on google about this problem.

Comment: How to analysis? Try a "`ssh -vvv git@localhost`" and check the permissions of `.ssh` directory (700) and `id_rsa(.pub)` files (600). See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3712443/creating-ssh-keys-for-gerrit-and-hudson/3712619#3712619 or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5470680/gitosis-post-receive-hook-to-deploy-repository-getting-public-key-errors/5471139#5471139 for illustration.

Comment: Have you generated rsa keys for sshd on server machine?
It may also be the case of different ssh versions on client and server machine.

Comment: @shark555 I don't know why server need a rsa key? I don't know what differences between ssh versions on client and server, so I generate a new rsa key on server and copy to client and add public key to authorized_keys on server. But it still doesn't work.

Comment: Try to fiddle with "Protocol" setting in sshd.conf on the server.
Check ssh server log also.

Comment: @shark555 it drives me mad. I try to generate RSA1 key, and git bash can find it but it return same error. I use ssh-host-config to generate a sshd service, and keep sshd_config as origin.

Comment: Are you able JUST login with ssh ? I would like to know if it's git specific problem or rather something more serious. Maybe you should just try different SSH server for Windows?

Comment: @shark555 I think it is problem that I have try many ssh(like copssh) and never clean system, so there is something wrong about Git or keys. In fact I have set up git server on my other machine for once, and I can ssh with Git Bash. But thank for your help. Have a good day.

Comment: If you have checked all the usual stuff (permissions, etc.) and you still get those messages, they do not necessarily indicate that anything is wrong with your RSA type 2 key. I have seen those exact messages on a working/valid RSA type 2 private key. The messages seem to be related to checking if it is a type 1 key or some other type of key. A key with those messages (using the -vvv option) WILL STILL WORK. I am logged into my server with such a key right now.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

I had this problem today and I realize that I was connected to 2 differente networks (LAN and WLAN), I solved it just disconnecting the cable from my Ethernet adapter. I suppose that the problem is caused because the ssh key is tied with the MAC address of my wireless adapter. I hope this helps you.

Comment: hey, dude what a big thanks for you! I disenable the wireless adapter and then it works! Thanks again.

Comment: For me, just unplugging and then again plug-in the LAN cable solved the problem.

Comment: Thanks. I actually have 2 wireless adapter, sometimes one works, and sometimes another. Your post suggested me to enable the "old" one, and wah lah, git is working!

Comment: So, basically you just asked, "Is it plugged in?" I love it.

Comment: @akelec can't believe this worked but it did

Comment: I had the same issue with a VPN connection, after disabling the VPN it worked. thanks!!

Answer (score 52):

For fixing the issues add the Hostname for Git on `~/.ssh/config`,

```
Host github.com
 Hostname ssh.github.com
 Port 443
```

In my case github!

Comment: Thanks for your advice, It works for me. I had the same problem when I use VPN to connect to github,since github was blocked in China. Via VPN I found http is ok ,but when I use ssh with default port 22 and default host name github.com,"kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host" error always happened.

Comment: Maybe you need 
`chown $USER ~/.ssh/config` and `chmod 644 ~/.ssh/config` if you meet the error `Bad owner or permissions`

Comment: Was in an airport on free wifi, and it blocked me on port 22.
Implemented this, and everything worked perfectly (after I confirmed the authenticity of the host).

Comment: adding hostname worked for me!

Comment: Worked for me, thanks! I am in mainland China too.

Answer (score 30):

I just ran into this today and it was because the server I was trying to connect to was overloaded with processing. So it may be possible that the server is low on memory or CPU starved.

Comment: Really, it happened to me when a server (if it's interesting, with RHEL) had "hanged" due to 100% CPU usage. Nasty thing.

Comment: too true, it happens with GitLab all the time and whenever it does, it returns a 500 error on the website. Annoying much!

Comment: Github.com has been failing due to a lot of timeouts. We get a variety of errors, including this one, depending on the system. Not sure what's happening on their side, but this week (2019-04-15) has been really slow despite their status page showing perfect :)

Answer (score 17):

Just enter on the server side :

```
echo 'SSHD: ALL' >> /etc/hosts.allow
```

It sorted it out for me.

Comment: Yes, denyhosts sometimes can deny your address (debian 7)

Comment: I tried doing this and I got a permission denied...I tried using sudo and it still says permission denied...any fixes?

Comment: ^ Same: permission denied, even when including sudo

Comment: I think you can use `chmod 777 /etc/host.allow` and the append should work.

Comment: Do NOT chmod 777 that file. That's global access to guests. Instead, modify it properly: `sudo -s "echo 'SSHD: ALL' >> /etc/hosts.allow"`

Comment: when tried to do that i got permissin denied, still using sudo echo 'SSHD: ALL' >> /etc/hosts.allow, but I could solve it editing with sudo nano  /etc/hosts.allow, then I could add SSHD: ALL to that line. WORKED FOR ME! thanks

Comment: Thanks a bunch mate! This really helped!

Answer (score 15):

Hit the following `ssh restart` command in **linux**

```
prayag@prayag:~/backup/NoisyNeighbour$ service ssh restart 
stop: Rejected send message, 1 matched rules; type="method_call", sender=":1.75" (uid=1417676764 pid=5933 comm="stop ssh ") interface="com.ubuntu.Upstart0_6.Job" member="Stop" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination="com.ubuntu.Upstart" (uid=0 pid=1 comm="/sbin/init")
start: Rejected send message, 1 matched rules; type="method_call", sender=":1.76" (uid=1417676764 pid=5930 comm="start ssh ") interface="com.ubuntu.Upstart0_6.Job" member="Start" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination="com.ubuntu.Upstart" (uid=0 pid=1 comm="/sbin/init")
```

Comment: The fact that restarting helps is ... worrisome.

Comment: @Raphael it may be because the SSH service was not started: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128894/ssh-exchange-identification-connection-closed-by-remote-host-not-using-hosts-d/439945#439945

Answer (score 13):

Make sure you are not connect to any kind of VPN.

Comment: @deborah-digges actually you need to make sure you VPN host has access to your git repository. If it does you should be fine.

Comment: This was my issue - disconnected from the VPN and it worked fine.

Answer (score 8):

Got the same error message.  Turning off WiFi and turning it back on again worked for me.

Answer (score 8):

After removing/deleting the `rm ~/.ssh/known_hosts`, my issue was fixed

Answer (score 5):

I solved it after changing the ssh port & MaxStartups variable in /etc/ssh/sshd_config to ,

```
port 2244
MaxStartups 100
```

Then, restart the service

```
service sshd restart
```

If still it does not work, restart you system.

Answer (score 4):

if hostname does not work, try IP address.

This is going on right now so I have to say.  I try to ssh with my host name and it does not work

```
ssh root@host.example.net
```

this gives the error "ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host"

this USED to work one hour back.

BUT, and here is the interesting part, the IP address works!

```
ssh root@192.168.0.100
```

(of course the actual IP address is different)

Go figure!

Answer (score 3):

Remove any config in `~/.ssh/config` or other ssh config places which will disallow it to reach to Github servers

In my case it was below config, and I wasn't connected to VPN.

```
Host *
  ProxyJump 10.0.0.50
```

Note :-
If I am connected to VPN, This config would mean git clone or any git operation will be send via VPN which might be slow depending on type of VPN we are using.

Comment: This is also my case, just start vpn, then it works.

Answer (score 3):

Disconnecting and reconnecting to the current network worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Hi I fix this on one vps service,  restarting it, other way is if you have a console from your service o any other way to run a command in your remote machine the only command you must run is restart the ssh daemon and enjoy!! :P

```
/etc/init.d/ssh restart
```

Answer (score 2):

We migrated our git host instance/servers this morning to a new data center and while being connected to both: VPN (from remote/home) or when in office network, I got the same error and was not able to connect to clone any GIT repo.

```
Cloning into 'some_repo_in_git_dev'...
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

This will help if you are connecting to some or all servers via a jump host server.

Earlier in my **~/.ssh/config file**, my setting to connect were:

```
Host * !ssh.somejumphost.my.company.com
     ProxyCommand ssh -q -W %h:%p ssh.somejumphost.my.company.com
```

What this means is, for any SSH based connection, it will connect to any ***** server via the given jump host server **except/by ignoring** "ssh.somejumphost.my.company.com" server (as we don't want to connect to a jump host via jump host server.

To FIX the issue, all I did was, change the config to ignore git server as well:

```
Host * !ssh.somejumphost.my.company.com !mycompany-git.server.com !OrMyCompany-some-other-git-instance.server.com
     ProxyCommand ssh -q -W %h:%p ssh.somejumphost.my.company.com
```

So, now to connect to mycompany-git.server.com while doing git clone (git SSH url), I'm telling SSH not to use a jump host for those two extra git instances/servers.

Answer (score 2):

For me this was caused by a limit on the number of concurrent ssh sessions.  I added the two params below to /etc/ssh/sshd_config and then things worked.

```
echo 'MaxSessions 2000' >> /etc/ssh/sshd_config
echo 'MaxStartups 2000' >> /etc/ssh/sshd_config
service ssh restart
```

Answer (score 2):

Similar to Arun Sangal the problem lied in an in .ssh/config entry

```
Host my.sshhost.com
  ProxyCommand ssh -q -W %h:%p myremotemachine.my.company.com
```

The remote machine was added to avoid with ssh for VPN connections and worked well. But for the vacation period I switched off the myremotemachine and run into the described problem.

Answer (score 2):

To solve this edit /etc/ssh/ssh_config and comment the following line
1

## ProxyCommand /usr/bin/sss_ssh_knownhostsproxy -p %p %h

https://www.evilbox.ro/linux/solve-ssh_exchange_identification-connection-closed-by-remote-host/ for reference

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Answer (score 2):

Today Gitlab Server was in maintainence. [Please check](https://gitlab.com/) if it's working later.

Answer (score 1):

Got the same error too when connecting to GitHub with ssh as I move from one workplace to another. according to my situation, it seems that dns servers of different networks may get various ip address of github and the known_hosts file not identify it when changes happened. So change dns or switch back original network may work.

Answer (score 1):

You can get "ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host" if your `sshd` service is not operational!

If you have access to the server check you have the `sshd` service running with:

```
  ps aux | grep ssh
```

and check it is listening on port 22:

```
 netstat -plant | grep :22
```

[more details here](http://www.ewhathow.com/2013/09/how-to-check-if-ssh-is-running-on-linux/)

Answer (score 1):

Simple server reboot solved the problem for me. Try hard reboot , if dont work after soft reboot.

Answer (score 1):

Please use Port 7999 and Try. it will work

Answer (score 1):

I solved it this way.

`ssh -vvv <username>@github.com` to see github IP.

Then opened browser and opened github via IP to find it was an issue with firewall.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced this today and I just do a:

```
12345@123456 MINGW64 ~/development/workspace/test (develop)
$ git status
Refresh index: 100% (1204/1204), done.
On branch develop
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/develop'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean

12345@123456 MINGW64 ~/development/workspace/test (develop)
$ git fetch
```

Then all worked again.

Answer (score 1):

For me, the issue was that there was a proxy set in /etc/ssh/ssh_config and it was down, solved the issue by whitelisting the remote git IP and removing the proxy line.

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

In windows machine, remove the content of config file present in C:\Users{yourusername}.ssh

This worked well for me.

Comment: Bad idea in most cases. Your config was obviously wrong and the defaults were better.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a VPN, Turn it off and try to push again.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I am developing a script for setting up Raspberry Pies. I forgot to add in that script enabling of the ssh.