# git: fatal: Could not read from remote repository

Tags: git

I am trying to set git up with http://danielmiessler.com/study/git/#website to manage my site.

I have gotten to the last step in the instructions:  git push website +master:refs/heads/master

I am working using the git ming32 command line in win7

```
$ git push website +master:refs/heads/master
Bill@***.com's password:
Connection closed by 198.91.80.3
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

One problem here may be that the program is looking for Bill@***.com. when I connect via ssh to my site I have a different username( lets say 'abc'). so maybe this should be abc@***.com. If so I don't know how to change this or if I can push under an alias

Comment: I had the same issue, sometimes this error happens when git server isn't reachable or has something like "internal server error".

Comment: First please look at `.git/config` file and see everything is in order. It had wrong set-url and origin values for me.

Comment: Perhaps this would solve the issue: https://help.github.com/articles/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/

Comment: A related issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10127818/ssh-exchange-identification-connection-closed-by-remote-host-under-git-bash

Comment: can you show me the correct order of .git/config and also the .ssh/config ... coz i'm confused abit tough.

Comment: For me this happened because I was using the wrong type of slashes in the URL.

Comment: In my case, I had to turn off my WiFi and turn it back on again. Rest of internet was working, including fast.com, but for some reason no GitHub operations were working.

Comment: For me, SSH works fine in Git Bash (Windows) but not in Powershell or Command prompt.

Comment: So many answers. This post resolved my issue for having a work and personnal git account both using SSH https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/manage-multiple-github-accounts-the-ssh-way-2dadc30ccaca/

Comment: In my case I typed the remote url incorrectly. The error is not distinguishable from failed ssh authentication.

Comment: For me this was caused by the recent change of RSA SSH host key by GitHub. More details can be found [here](https://github.blog/2023-03-23-we-updated-our-rsa-ssh-host-key/). In short, I needed to remove the old GitHub RSA key from ~/.ssh/known_hosts and add the new one. To be on the safe side, it's better to add the key found at the same link above.

Comment: **If you're using WSL or similar**, make sure your SSH key is in there too...

Answer (score 169, accepted):

You can specify the username that SSH should send to the remote system as part of your remote's URL.  Put the username, followed by an `@`, before the remote hostname.

```
git remote set-url website abc@***.com:path/to/repo
```

Comment: ps , is there a way to add the password in so I don't keep having to type it?

Comment: edit the file `.git/config` which has the remote url parameter

Comment: @user61629: I know I'm late to the party, but you should consider using private/public key pairs instead of passwords.

Comment: Which user name? Computer username or github username?

Comment: For Github, you always use the username `git`. Example: `git@github.com:mayoff/uiimage-from-animated-gif.git` Github figures out your identity by looking at what SSH key you send.

Comment: For me, I had followed all the steps mentioned in [Adding new ssh key][1] and rest of the auxiliary links related to this issue.
But the issue was network access. Solution - using VPN to access my Github Enterprise. (in my case Georgia Tech VPN for github.gatech.edu)


  [1]: https://help.github.com/en/articles/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account

Comment: @Sayanee: that file only exists in existing repos, not in new ones you're trying to clone.

Comment: It is not clear enough and my guessing about the answer does not work.

Comment: Thanks that worked when I changed https to ssh and added git@  to the hostname. Its been killing me finding a fit to this.

Answer (score 548):

Your ssh key most likely had been removed from ssh agent

```
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

where id_rsa is a ssh key associated with git repo

**Update**

You may get `Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.` error to resolve that you need to start the agent first by:

```
eval `ssh-agent -s`
```

Comment: This worked for me!  I spent a long time trying to configure my ~/.ssh/config file to use different keys for different hosts, thought that this file was the problem.  In the end, it must have been using the right key for the right host, but that key had been "removed".  so `ssh-add ~/.ssh/theKeyInQuestion` got me back up and running with this repo, didnt know the key removed, or what "removed" even means but at least I was able to get authenticated again. SSH is a total mystery to me even after months of dealing with authentication issues.  ssh agent issues are one more thing to be aware of!

Comment: Thanks a Lot.. This finally worked for me after trying to create, delete, etc the SSH keys into my GitLab account.... Thanks!!

Comment: This solved my issue. I already have the newly generated ssh key added on the server.  This key need to be added !!

Comment: This solved it for me, I don't understand why.. It used to work and all of a sudden not, is there a process that removes the key from the agent, can it happen on accident?

Comment: Why does it happen? It worked all the day but in the evening it stopped to work. This answer helped.

Comment: In MacBook I use `ssh-add -k ~/.ssh/id_rsa`

Comment: @MiguelStevens and @Andrey: had the same thing happen after I ran `ssh-keygen`. The fix was to log out and back in. This `ssh-add` solution did not work.

Comment: I'm getting `Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.`.

Comment: @DanDascalescu try to use `eval \`ssh-agent -s\`` to start the ssh-agent firstly

Comment: In my case, the key was stored in `id_ed25519.pub` instead of  `id_rsa` so running `ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_ed25519` after `eval \`ssh-agent -s\`` worked for me. Thanks for pointing towards the right direction!

Comment: Thanks. This worked for me but not on the first try. Even after trying these commands, making sure I have the correct SSH key in both local repo and Github account and restarting Windows terminal, I still got the same error. I closed the Windows terminal and used Git Bash and everything worked as expected.

Comment: Is there any way to automatically perform this step when instance is turned on. I restarted my instance and previous key was removed.

Comment: After updating my MacBook from Big Sur to Monterey, the ssh-agent did not pick up my id_ed25519 key by default, just the id_rsa key. I added it manually and was then able to login as I had done before the upgrade.

Answer (score 308):

I was facing same issue a while ago...

my .git/config had

```
url = git@github.com:manishnakar/polymer-demo.git
```

I replaced it with

```
url = https://github.com/manishnakar/polymer-demo.git
```

and it works now:)

Comment: how is this not higher ranked? git@github totally does not work for me

Comment: If the repo owner has not set up `ssh` keys then you will likely have this issue. The fix as indicated is to use `https` instead, or have the repo owner set up `ssh`

Comment: @smileham this switch the distant link with the repo from a ssh based auth to an https protocol (it will prompt for usr/pwd if required)

Comment: this is the correct answer, it worked instantly for me.

Comment: For anyone who got the `git remote set-url ...` wrong like me OR who foolishly has a Big Case Alphabet in their username (e.g PeDro) like me (!) should follow this. It worked :)

Comment: Works like a charm

Comment: Also working for bitbucket, just replace github with it. Thanks!

Comment: This is not an answer. It changes the protocol over which you authenticate. This is not a solution to ssh setup, but totally different way of talking to your git repo

Comment: In addition to this had to git fetch as I noticed the preview of the next push was pushing every commit again

Comment: HTTPS is no longer valid for github.

Comment: Solved it for me on GitLab too! Note that for gitlab there's a `/` instead of `:`  - `git remote set-url https://{server}@gitlab.com/{user}/{project}.git`

Comment: in windows https: path worked for me, thanks for the answer

Comment: Worked for me in GitKraken. I had a repo which was working with github and gitkraken, and then stopped working with this error. In the gitkraken UI I selected (in the left panel) `Remote->origin->Edit origin`, and then changed the Pull URL and Push URL from `git@github.com:` to `https://github.com/`. Fixed!

Answer (score 167):

Make sure you have correct url in `.git/config`

```
url = git@github.com:username/repo.git
```

If it's your first push, you'll need to set up correct upstream

```
$ git push -u origin master
```

You can check which key is used by:

```
$ ssh -vvv git@github.com
```

The reply should contain something like this:

```
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: ~/.ssh/id_rsa
...
You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```

Also it's possible to define rules for ssh in `~/.ssh/config`, e.g. based on aliases:

```
   Host github
      HostName github.com 
      User git
      IdentityFile "~/.ssh/id_rsa"

   Host git
      HostName github.com 
      User git
      IdentityFile "~/.ssh/some_other_id"
```

You can set connect to different ports, use different username etc. for each alias.

Comment: Thank you!! At some point when I cloned my repo, the `url` was set to `https://github.com/user/repo.git` (without `git@github.com`) and so it refused to use my SSH key. Maybe it's because I cloned it using GIthub for Windows originally (?)

Comment: I've had to change `url = ssh://github.com/RaphaelBossek/dev-atlassian-jira-proman.git` to `url = ssh://git@github.com/RaphaelBossek/dev-atlassian-jira-proman.git` and it worked again

Comment: Damnit, you are awesome. I tried so many other solutions. My url was https: as well :(

Comment: The `-vvv` hint was helpful for me. Now I see that it's saying "Connection closed by XXX.XXX.XXX.X port 22".

Comment: Ahhh, DeployHQ says "BitBucket is currently experiencing minor service problems. Please check their status page for more information. https://status.bitbucket.org" Bingo.

Comment: The [official documentation](https://help.github.com/articles/using-ssh-over-the-https-port/) helped me set the correct port and URL for GitHub access via SSH

Comment: What if you're trying to clone a repo? There's no `.git/config`.

Comment: @DanDascalescu Then simply check that your're not cloning a `https://...` URI to the repo (the ssh config then doesn't apply).

Comment: Perfect, thank you for this answer, I indeed had only `Host github.com` settings defined in `~/.ssh/config` while I was trying to access `gitlab.com` already

Answer (score 39):

I had a wrong ssh private key for Bitbucket along with the right one in ssh agent.

Deleted all keys first

```
ssh-add -D
```

Then added just the right key.

```
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Comment: what is id_rsa ?

Comment: @S.M.FazleRabbi id_rsa is the default name for the key file when you create the ssh key

Comment: Of course your key may not be called `id_rsa` in which case use the name of your key instead.

Comment: Worked for me! I have 2 different ssh keys, for different github spaces.

Answer (score 31):

Make sure ssh-agent is running by executing the following command on your terminal:

```
eval $(ssh-agent -s)
```

Source: [Github documentation](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys/#step-3-add-your-key-to-the-ssh-agent)

Comment: This fixes an issue for me as well. Thanks

Comment: This fixed it for me as well. Is there something I should be doing to make sure it is running in the future? Like put it as an entry in my `.zshrc` file?

Comment: This did it for me

Answer (score 28):

Try removing the GIT_SSH environment variable with `unset GIT_SSH`.  This was the cause of my problem.

Comment: Works.. I wonder where I got GIT_SSH environment variable from :)

Comment: For windows remove GIT_SSH environment variable from advanced options menu. Worked for me.

Comment: How? What do I write in the terminal to do that?

Comment: Fixed the issue for me as well

Comment: Fixed it for me too. But why does this cause the problem in the first place?

Comment: This fixed it for me as well. I use Cygwin as my preferred terminal. It has its own ssh.exe file which is configured properly and works fine. I suspect Cygwin looks for the GIT_SSH variable and will use that if it's there. I recently installed Git onto my Windows machines (as opposed to only having it inside of Cygwin). The Git installer set GIT_SSH to use Plink.exe, which probably wasn't configured as my Cygwin was. Once I removed GIT_SSH, Cygwin returned to normal.

Answer (score 28):

This is usually caused due to the SSH key is not matching with the remote.

**Solutions:**

1. Go to terminal and type the following command (Mac, Linux) replace with your email id.

   ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "you@email.com"
2. Copy the generated key using following command starting from word ssh.

   cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
3. Paste it in github, bitbucket or gitlab respective of your remote.
4. Save it.

Answer (score 20):

I had the same problem.

This error means that you have not specified your remote URL location upon which your code will push.

You can set remote URL by 2 (mainly) ways:

1. Specify remote URL via executing command on Git Bash.

   - Navigate to your project directory
   - Open Git Bash
   - Execute command:

     - `git remote set-url origin <https://abc.xyz/USERNAME/REPOSITORY.git>`
2. Mention remote URL direct in config file

   - Navigate to your project directory
   - Move to **.git** folder
   - Open **config** file in text editor
   - Copy and paste below lines

     - `[remote "origin"]
        url = https://abc.xyz/USERNAME/REPOSITORY.git
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*`

For more detailed info visit this [link](https://help.github.com/articles/changing-a-remote-s-url/).

Comment: thanks so much!!!  I tried everything and this worked finally.

Answer (score 12):

Another workaround:

Sometimes this happens to me because of network problems. I don't understand the root problem fully, but switching to a different sub-network or using VPN solves it

Comment: Exactly my case. Wish I had read this comment. After few hours of debugging, thought of using VPN and it worked.

Comment: For me, just "trying again" worked. No idea what the hiccup was.

Answer (score 10):

Pretty straightforward solution that worked for me, see below:-

###### Problem

```
$ git clone git@github.com:xxxxx/xxxx.git my-awesome-proj
Cloning into 'my-awesome-proj'...
ssh: connect to host github.com port 22: Connection timed out
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

###### This should also timeout

```
$ ssh -T git@github.com
ssh: connect to host github.com port 22: Connection timed out
```

###### This might work

```
$ ssh -T -p 443 git@ssh.github.com
Hi xxxx! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```

###### Override SSH settings

```
$ vim ~/.ssh/config

# You can also manually open the file and copy/paste the section below
# Add section below to it
Host github.com
  Hostname ssh.github.com
  Port 443
```

###### Then try again

```
$ ssh -T git@github.com
Hi xxxxx! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not
provide shell access.
```

###### Try cloning now (should work)

```
$ git clone git@github.com:xxxxxx/xxxxx.git my-awesome-proj
Cloning into 'my-awesome-proj'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 15, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (15/15), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (14/14), done.
remote: Total 15 (delta 0), reused 15 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (15/15), 22.90 KiB | 4.58 MiB/s, done.
```

Reference: here => [Use HTTPS with Port 443](https://gist.github.com/Tamal/1cc77f88ef3e900aeae65f0e5e504794)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31187769)

Comment: This did help me. It suddenly stopped working and this was the way to fix it.

Answer (score 9):

I had the same error. 
The solution was following:
I've corrected my url in `.git/config`.
Just copied that from HTTPS clone URL. That would be something like that:

```
url = https://github.com/*your*git*name*/*your*git*app*.git
```

It worked.

Comment: if i wrote this on my config file under windows os, the error arose differently, it said... "/c/Users/asus/.ssh/config: line 5: Bad configuration option: url"

Comment: using https over ssh is work fine, it asks username and password

Comment: @Kiran, that's not fine.

Answer (score 7):

After doing some research I've finally got solution for this, you have declared a environment variable to plink.exe path. So if you remove that path, reopen the git bash and try cloning through SSH it will work.

Refer to this link

http://sourceforge.net/p/forge/site-support/2959/#204c

Answer (score 7):

If after"git push origin master" command u see the error "could not read from remote repository" then try this out

```
1.ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "youremail"
2.eval $(ssh-agent -s)
3.ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
4.clip < ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub(it copies the ssh key that has got generated)
5.then go to your remote repository on github and goto settings-> SSH and GPG keys ->new SSH key ->enter any title and paste the copied SSH key and save it
6. now give git push origin master
```

Answer (score 5):

**I was facing the same issue. so here's the way i resolved the same**

**Step 1:**

create a new ssh key:-

```
ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -C "your_email@example.com"
```

**Step 2:**

copy the ssh key on clipboard :-

```
pbcopy < ~/.ssh/id_ed25519.pub
```

**Step 3:**

now paste copied ssh key to the corresponding git repository

**Step 4:**
Start the ssh-agent in the background.

```
$ eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
> Agent pid 59566
```

**Step 5:**
now try accesing the repo

```
git clone git@github.com:username/repo-name.git
```

**Step 6:**

if still you see the issue then check the ssh config file

```
vim ~/.ssh/config
```

the content should look like

```
Host github.com
  AddKeysToAgent yes
  UseKeychain yes
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519
```

**Step 7:**

> Add your SSH private key to the ssh-agent and store your passphrase in
> the keychain

```
ssh-add --apple-use-keychain ~/.ssh/id_ed25519
```

**Step 8:**

Now try again it should work

```
git clone git@github.com:username/repo-name.git
```

Answer (score 4):

In your .git/config file

```
[remote "YOUR_APP_NAME"]
    url = git@heroku.com:YOUR_APP_NAME.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/YOUR_APP_NAME/*
```

And simply

```
git push YOUR_APP_NAME master:master
```

Answer (score 4):

I had a perfectly fine working git and suddenly I got that error when I tried to push to the master. As I found out, it was because the repository host had problems.

If you using GitHub or Bitbucket you can easily check the status at

https://status.github.com/messages or https://status.bitbucket.org/

[image]

Comment: GitHub's link no longer functions. Try: https://www.githubstatus.com/

Answer (score 4):

If you use Gitlab than you might need to log in and accept Gitlab new terms, before you try to pull or push.

Comment: Why the downvote? At same day I solved my problem, it had something to do with new gitlab terms.

Comment: Please remove your downvote. This is a valid answer, it happend after gitlab terms change. Accepting gitlab new terms might solve the problem.

Answer (score 4):

I have tried everything including generating new key, adding to the GitHub account, editing **.ssh/config** and **.git/config**. But still it was giving me the same error.
Then I tried following command and it does work successfully.

```
ssh-agent bash -c 'ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa; git clone git@github.com:username/repo.git'
```

Comment: As mentioned, have you tried running `ssh -T git@github.com`? That worked for me.

Comment: @MikeS. No I did not try that. I will try, if I face similar issue again. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use HTTPS for Git:

Type this into the Terminal:

```
$ git remote set-url origin abc@***.com:path/to/httpURLRepo
```

Then commit:

```
$ git add .
$ git commit -m "This is the commit message"
```

Comment: > For me, using https instead of ssh worked: **git clone https://gitlab.com/user/project.git**

Answer (score 4):

updated OCT 2020

In most of the case when you have more than one user access the same git server from a same client system, that time git server confused to with access key with the user both users allowed but when you fire command that time its used default  user.

```
ssh -T git@gitlab.com
```

see which user are activatly you try to push with that user

**the simple solution removes the unused user public key from the git server.**

then try to git fetch or pull, push it will work for me

Answer (score 4):

In my case,  The bitbucket's web ssh key setup UI is confusing.

Repository Settings -> Access keys -> Add key : Error

Personal settings -> SSH keys -> Add key : Ok

The public key registration screen is mutually exclusive. You must register the public key only in one place. It seems good to unify them on one screen.

Comment: This was exactly my problem, it is really strange why key that is added to the the repository didn't worked.

Answer (score 3):

For my case, I am using Corporate network (without internet connection) in office. In order to pull code from github, I set https proxy in gitbash and then use https instead of ssh to pull code,it works fine. However when comes to push code, the https proxy won't work. So either switch to Internet network (with internet connection) or set ssh proxy can solve the problem.

Comment: Yes it does the same with some free wifi in coffee places

Answer (score 3):

In my case I was using an ssh key with a password to authenticate with github. I hadn't set up pageant properly in Windows (only in cygwin).  The missing steps were to point the git_ssh environment variable to plink.exe.  Also, you need to get github.com into the plink known_hosts.

```
   plink github.com
   y
   <then ctrl-c>
```

Hope this helps!

I sure wish intellij would have given me a more useful error, or better yet asked me to type in the ssh key password.

Answer (score 3):

```
user@server:/etc/nginx$ cat .git/config 
...
[remote "origin"]
    url = git@gitlab.com:user/.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
...
```

---

1. Use ssh instead of https.
2. To use ssh key in git (add ssh key).
3. If you are root, use the ssh key.

---

```
$ sudo ssh-keygen
$ cat /root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub 

$ git init
$ git add file
$ git commit -m "add first file"
$ git remote add origin git@gitlab.com:user/example.git 
$ git push -u origin master
```

Answer (score 3):

I solved this issue by **restarting the terminal** (open a new window/tab).

So if you don't really want/need to understand the underlying problem, test method is worth a try before digging deeper :)

Comment: This didn't work but I had to turn off my Wi-Fi and then turn it back on.

Comment: Or, if this doesn't work, restart the computer. Especially if your setup worked properly before.

Answer (score 3):

I meet the problem just now and fix it by:  `git config user.email "youremail"`.

---

update:
The root cause maybe my poor network and poor proxy.
I still don't know why it happened, but every time has this error, this command works!!!

Answer (score 3):

### My issue was resolved by using these commands on Windows 11

**1. I opened up the Git Bash command and started ssh-agent.**

```
eval "$(ssh-agent -s)" // this command only work in git bash.
```

**2. Added by ssh-key**

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "your_email@example.com"  //it must be 4096
ssh-add id_rsa
```

**3. Check properly added or not.**

```
ssh-add -l
```

**4. Uploaded its public key on GitHub as (Authorization key)**

```
cat id_rsa.pub | clip
```

**5. Unset any proxy and GIT_SSH variable**

```
unset GIT_SSH
git config --global --unset http.proxy
git config --global --unset https.proxy
```

**6. Must check github.com should be resolved.**

```
ping github.com
```

**7. Now check Connectivity with Github.**

```
ssh -T git@github.com
```

**Output**

> The authenticity of host 'github.com (20.207.73.82)' can't be
> established. ED25519 key fingerprint is
> SHA256:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx This key is not known by
> any other names Are you sure you want to continue connecting
> (yes/no/[fingerprint])? yes Warning: Permanently added 'github.com'
> (ED25519) to the list of known hosts. Hi MHamzaRajput! You've
> successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.

Answer (score 3):

I resolved this issue by change my `url` from

```
https://gitlab.com/{gitlab_user}/project_repo.git
```

to

```
https://{gitlab_user}@gitlab.com/gitlab_user/project_repo.git
```

using command

```
git remote set-url https://{gitlab_user}@gitlab.com/gitlab_user/project_repo.git
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually I tried a lot of things to make it work on Win7, since changing the SSH exectun fron native to build-it and backwards and the same error.
By chance, i change it to HTTPS in the ".git/config" file as:

```
[remote "origin"]
        url = https://github.com/user_name/repository_name.git
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

and it finally worked. So maybe it could work for you as well.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and after a while I saw I'm under root user (with sudo -s). May this help for someone.

Comment: I confirm that even when you have set up ssh key on your machine and on the BitBucket, it will still display this error if you try to execute 'git pull' with a 'sudo' command.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem using gitbash on windows 10. I tried several things to solve this problem, the major ones being these:

1. Recreated my ssh keys and updated to bitbucket. Didn't help
2. Turned on debugging using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38706495/3885927) and found out that I was getting "shell request failed on channel 0" as asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27021641/3885927)
3. Rebooted my windows PC

None of the above helped. I ended up re-installing [Git for windows](https://gitforwindows.org/) This took only a few minutes as compared to other things I did and it solved the problem!

Comment: why I didn't see your answer 2 days ago? I already spend to much time for this fix.... :(

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I was trying to clone with `sudo`. As per Github's doc, you shouldn't use sudo with git clone:
https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/error-permission-denied-publickey#should-the-sudo-command-be-used-with-git

What I did is give the currrent user permission to edit the directory (Debian 9):

```
chown myuser:root .
```

Then cloned without `sudo` and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

Not the OP' problem, but if you're working in a **GitHub organization/ team**, you might not have write permissions on the repository. Unfortunately, git doesn't show more specific permissions errors. In my case, I was working on a private repository, and had been given "Triage" or "Read" access.

For more information about repository access for each permission level, see [GitHub documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/setting-up-and-managing-organizations-and-teams/repository-permission-levels-for-an-organization).

The link to change this on GitHub is `https://github.com/orgs/ORGANISATION_NAME/teams/TEAM_NAME/repositories`, where you can change the permissions given to the team.

[image: Screenshot of github organisation's team's repository's tab]

Answer (score 1):

For those having this problem on a private remote repo. make sure you have accepted the Xcode agreement on the remote server: it took we weeks to find out this fix

Use this command from the command line:  sudo xcodebuild -license

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was the postBuffer..

```
git config --global http.postBuffer 524288000
```

For reference read: https://gist.github.com/marcusoftnet/1177936

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error, which brought me to this answer that didn't help me.
I was trying to create a new "bare" repository for the first time using the commands below to track to an NTFS location:

```
cd myrepository
git init --bare \\myserver.mycompany.local\myrepository.git
git init
git status
git add .
git status
git commit -m "Initial Commit"
git remote add origin \\myserver.mycompany.local\myrepository.git
git push -u origin master
git status
```

My problem turned out to be using the back slashes instead of forward slashes in the NTFS location when trying to add origin to set the (new) tracked upstream branch.

I had to remove the origin using:

```
git remote rm origin
```

Then add the origin again using the expected forward slashes

```
git remote add origin //myserver.mycompany.local/myrepository.git
```

Hope this helps someone in the future.

Answer (score 1):

I've got this error after changing computers. I'm using SourceTree with Bitbucket.

So I had to add the SSH key generated by SourceTree, on the new computer, in Bitbucket Settings > Security > SSH keys, while connected to my Bitbucket account on the web.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting this problem intermittently, where most of the time it would not give the error message. The solution for me was to configure LDAP correctly after my LDAP server's IP address had changed.

The `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb` configuration for LDAP was pointing to a non-existent IP address, and so changing the host to point to the proper hostname for the LDAP server fixed the issue.

To diagnose the issue, use the `gitlab-ctl tail` command to help you find stacktraces. For me, I found this stacktrace:

```
==> /var/log/gitlab/gitlab-rails/production.log <==

Net::LDAP::Error (No route to host - connect(2) for 10.10.10.12:389):
  /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/net-ldap-0.16.0/lib/net/ldap/connection.rb:72:in `open_connection'
...
```

Make the changes to the host value in `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb`

```
gitlab_rails['ldap_servers'] = YAML.load <<-'EOS'
   main: 
     label: 'My LDAP'
     # this was an IP address
     # host: '10.10.10.12'
     host: 'internal-ldap-server' # this is the fix
     port: 389
```

After changing the config file above, be sure to reconfigure gitlab

```
gitlab-ctl reconfigure
```

Answer (score 1):

It could be a Network issue.

Try doing the `ssh -vvvT git@gitlab.com`. If the server hangs unexpectedly it could be a dodgy network connection.

Put the following in your ~/.ssh/config

```
IPQoS lowdelay throughput
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have set **recievepack**  or **uploadpack**
in my case i got the error after setting them by mistake

```
receivepack = powershell git receive-pack
```

in my case in `.git/config`

You can remove them as by the answer bellow

https://stackoverflow.com/a/26207308/7668448

Or by directly modifying `.git/config`

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you need to use full URL with `ssh://` scheme:

```
ssh://git@yourhost:port/path/repo.git
```

or with specified port:

```
ssh://git@yourhost:port/path/repo.git
```

For me it solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

run into this because I am in China with Great Firewall...

> kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host fatal:
>   Could not read from remote repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository
>   exists.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the problem and it's solution was written right in front of me. Earlier that day I edited the /etc/ssh/ssh_config file and added some keys. The error said:

```
/etc/ssh/ssh_config: line 52: Bad configuration option: allowusers
/etc/ssh/ssh_config: terminating, 1 bad configuration options
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

I deleted the `allowusers` key and it's value and everything worked as expected.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and resolved by updating to the latest git version

Answer (score 1):

My solution was quite simple actually. I just had to copy and place the fingerprint from this question "Please type 'yes', 'no' or the fingerprint" instead of just hitting enter.

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to add to this question. I had Git setup to use PLink and Pageant for authentication and I was also getting the error `FATAL ERROR: Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey)`. I had Pageant opened but the error was still showing up. The problem? I didn't have the private key loaded in Pageant (to add a key, follow [these instructions](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.60/htmldoc/Chapter9.html#pageant-mainwin-addkey)). It was that simple.

Answer (score 0):

When using putty/pageant, make sure you did not forget to add the correct SSH key to pageant, else this error shows up. DUH

Answer (score 0):

Go to MINGW32 terminal put this Command : git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/(branch Name)

Answer (score 0):

If you are still getting the same error, please make sure that in the git settings->ssh tab->ssh client to use is set to **openSSH**[image]

Answer (score 0):

According to my experience, one of the reasons **this problem occured** is because you have an **unstable internet connection**.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue; simply you can run this on your command window:

git remote add origin https://your/repository/url

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the "I had the same problem and...", I am also using git via Ming32 (git bash) shell in Windows.

In my case the repo requires me to type a password, not using SSH key, but it was *not* prompting for the password, just saying "fatal: Could not read...", although I could SSH in normally, using plink and ssh, and had set both known-host keys.

I tried most of the recommendations here and in other SOs.

I found in the end **it worked fine in Powershell**, but not in git bash, with no changes or corrections.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to check all remotes you have configured with `git remote -v` If you had your repo configured to a remote that was deleted you will receive this error message:  `fatal: Could not read from remote repository. Please make sure you have the correct access rightsand the repository exists.` Even when trying to push or pull to an other (existing) remote. So if you have a remote that was deleted, you can remove with `git remote remove name-of-remote-to-remove` and after that you can push or pull to your existing remotes without problems.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error while trying to push code to my personal git from work - defaults point to work git. 
So I followed these steps:

1. Went to my personal git account and created repo with default settings
2. On terminal, git remote add origin git@github.com:/.git
3. git push --set-upstream origin master, ensuring that origin is upstream and the next commits can be made using git push only.

For some reason, no other way worked for me. Hope this helps someone working with 2 or more git accounts.

Answer (score 0):

I encounter this issue by enter many times error password.

so I have to change the MaxAuthTries to a bigger number:

open the `sshd_config` in server end:

```
vim  /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

change the MaxAuthTries number:

```
MaxAuthTries 100    # there I change to 100, you can change to a bigger than your current tries number
```

Answer (score 0):

In a rare case, you'll get "fatal: Could not read from remote repository" error, like in

```
[user@example.com repo]$ git fetch --all --prune
Fetching origin
exec request failed on channel 0
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

when Git server filesystem is full. To verify this, please run:

```
ssh -v ssh://git@yourhost/path/repo.git
```

If the server replies like this:

```
...
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /home/...
SHA256:...
debug1: Server accepts key: /home/...
SHA256:...
Authenticated to linux-git.....com ([xxx.xxx.xx.xx]:xx) using "publickey".
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: filesystem full
...
debug1: Remote: PTY allocation disabled.
PTY allocation request failed on channel 0
shell request failed on channel 0
```

then the disk space on the server is exhausted.

I understand that this answer won't get many up-votes; adding it for the sake of completeness.

P.S. It is also possible to use something like

```
GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -v" git pull
```

to diagnose the problem.

Answer (score 0):

To me, this occurs due to network. Your network might be slow. So change network or troubleshoot it.

Answer (score 0):

Had similar problem.
I've added ssh key to my account by generating it via [this](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent) instruction (`ssh-keygen`) or if you already have one add it and not generating new one.
Then I changed my global credentials via command shell, they also can be changed locally for project in project root directory(remove global flag) if you already cloned repo, but it wasn`t my case.
git config --global user.name "YourFirstname YourLastname"
git config --global user.email "youremail@email.com"

Answer (score 0):

Question has been already answered but here is another way of solving the problem https://medium.com/@deshpasheeto_sisu/error-fatal-could-not-read-from-remote-repository-f987007ee997

This might work for somebody who has no luck with other options.

Answer (score -1):

i just wanted to share that i found a easy fix for that:

**Access denied.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.**

just logout from gitlab and login again. The problems should then be fixed.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same error but if you pass the command again you will notice that you are prompted: `Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?`, and by writing "yes" and *then* hitting <kbd>enter</kbd> it should be resolved.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The output of the original post shows this is not happening. The ability to read is assumed here to make a question.

Comment: @PeterKrebs This particular question was prompted right before these same errors and typing "yes" resolved the problem.