# How to specify the username that SSH should send to the remote system using the git GUI

Tags: git

I'm using git_bash and the git GUI on win7.

From [git: fatal: Could not read from remote repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13509293/git-fatal-could-not-read-from-remote-repository):

```
You can specify the username that SSH should send to the remote system as part of your remote's URL. Put the username, followed by an @, before the remote hostname.

git remote set-url website abc@***.com:path/to/repo
```

Is there a way to run the above command from within the git gui, rather than the command line?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it while you're adding a new remote. (ctrl+a is the short command for that, the menus should be something like remotes->add remote).

So if you want to do it in git-gui I guess you've to remove the remote and then add a new  one.

However, that command is a one-time thing to execute in git-bash. I hardly see the problem with that.

An other way is to manually edit .git/config which includes all the configuration for your remotes.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to run the above command from within the git gui [sic!], rather than the command line?

No. There is no editing for remote URLs available. Instead you need to remove the remote URL and then add it again with the correct URL. Done.

Trigger a snapshot in your backup before you perform this in case you have unmerged changes compared with remote.