# git push heroku master Write failed: Connection reset by peer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku, push

I am getting this error when running this command 'git push heroku master'

Write failed: Connection reset by peer
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

I followed the instructions given from heroku site. Here is the link https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-rails3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sign into Heroku, click on your app, click on the Access tab, and make sure you're listed as a contributor or owner.

Then configure your SSH keys.
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/keys

Comment: I am listed as owner of the app.

Comment: Edited original answer. If you're listed as the owner the only thing I can think of is that you haven't properly configured your SSH keys.

Comment: I tried configure my SSH keys to Heroku but same error happening

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13509293/git-fatal-could-not-read-from-remote-repository

Comment: It was a issue with my network connection that wasn't allowing me to connect via ssh. Now It is working fine. Thanks for your help.