# Error pushing to Heroku after adding new domain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, dns

---

I recently added a new GoDaddy domain to my rails app.
Everything works fine when I push to git but when I try to push to Heroku using:

```
$ git push heroku
```

I get the following error:

```
fatal: 'heroku' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository
Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.
```

Is this problem occurring because I need to create another environment? The domain name for my GoDaddy website is listed under '$ heroku domains' but doesn't seem to be connected.

Any ideas would be helpful. TIA!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for your comment on answer below, its obvious that you should try

`git push prod master` instead of `git push heroku`

'heroku' and 'prod' it's just names of remote repositories. Heroku by default creates repos named accordingly - 'heroku'. As far as I know it could be changed to whatever you need

Answer (score 0):

This issue is probably unrelated to godaddy.  Try typing

```
git remote -v
```

this will give you a list of the remote repositories you have setup. If none are pointing to your app on heroku you'll need to set it up.

Refer to this on article from heroku dev center

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git

**EDIT**

As i suspected your heroku remote is named "prod" not "heroku"  try 'git push prod' that should work.

You might have to specify the branch in which case the command would be 'git push prod master'

**EDIT2**

It looks your are not yet authorized to push to heroku. The root problem can vary. I recommend starting with this article:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/keys

Also check this SO article

[git push heroku master Write failed: Connection reset by peer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19506158/git-push-heroku-master-write-failed-connection-reset-by-peer)

Comment: >when i do that, I get the following:  >origin git@github.com:appname/appname.git (fetch)  >origin git@github.com:appname/appname.git (push)  >prod git@heroku.com:appname/appname.git (fetch)  >prod git@heroku.com:appname/appname.git (push)

Comment: It seems like that should work but now I'm getting the following error messages: >Read from remote host heroku.com: Connection reset by peer >fatal: sha1 file '<stdout>' wrte error: Invalid argument > error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:appname.git'

Comment: It looks your are not yet authorized to push to heroku. The root problem can vary. I recommend starting with this article: