# git remote.branch.receivepack= git receive-pack

Tags: git

I need to remove this from my git config
When I run

```
git config --list
```

I get

```
stufff
stufff
remote.live.receivepack=git receive-pack
more stuff
```

I need to remove this since that is not the name of my remote, if I delete that entry from the config so that I am not pulling from that remote. I would like to remove that entry from the config all together

Comment: You can edit the `.git/config` file directly and remove the offending entry.

Comment: or `git config --unset remote.live.receivepack`

Comment: It doesn't appear in the config on the remote or the cloned remote on my local. I remember setting git config --global remote.live.receivepack = "git receive-pack".

Comment: Looks like unset is not affecting the entry it is still listed

Comment: try `git config --global --unset remote.live.receivepack`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`git config --list` will list results from up to 3 config files.

```
repo/.git/config - the repository config file  
~/.gitconfig - the global config file for your user  
/etc/gitconfig - the system config file for the machine you are on
```

Use '--unset' to delete a config entry.  With no options, `git config --unset` operates on the repository config. Use '--global' to specify your user config, and '--system' to specify the system config.

For your specific instance

```
git config --global --unset remote.live.receivepack
```