# How to fix request failed on channel 0

Tags: ssh, terminal, pty

When I want to connect to my server like this

```
ssh -a username@my-server.de -p 22
```

it gives me two error messages:

```
PTY allocation request failed on channel 0
shell request failed on channel 0
```

When I use the parameter `-T` the first error message goes away.
But how to fix the second one?
I can't connect. To other servers I can connect without any problems.

I'm on MAC OS 10.9.

The parameter `-v` shows me this debug output:

```
OpenSSH_6.2p2, OSSLShim 0.9.8r 8 Dec 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to xxx.your-server.de [188.40.3.15] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/xxx/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/xxx/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/xxx/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/xxx/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version mod_sftp/0.9.8
debug1: no match: mod_sftp/0.9.8
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA 55:f5:ca:ca:01:45:0f:7b:71:0a:1f:ba:9e:25:17:fb
debug1: Host 'xxx.your-server.de' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/xxx/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/xxx/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/xxx/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Next authentication method: password
```

After I enter the password, I get this:

```
debug1: Authentication succeeded (password).
Authenticated to xxx.your-server.de ([xxx.xxx.3.15]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LANG = de_DE.UTF-8
shell request failed on channel 0
```

Comment: The client is requesting a shell session with a TTY and the server is rejecting it. The server doesn't provide the client with a detailed reason why the request was rejected. You need to troubleshoot this on the server rather than the client.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You're right, the server does not provide this request. I don't know ho to find out where the problem is. I read some other posts before but they didn't match exactly my problem. Can anybody give me some hints, please?

Comment: Try `ssh [-neccessary options] /bin/bash -i`. This might give a more informative error message from the server side (e.g. "permission denied" or "segmentation fault")

Comment: The `debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version mod_sftp/0.9.8` line indicates that the remote server is proftpd+mod_sftp, and the mod_sftp module does not implement/support shell requests, only SFTP/SCP.  Thus the `shell request failed` error.

Comment: when the server is jenkins it only supports a limited command set, not a shell.
So it responds also with "shell request failed on channel 0"
when given an accepted command like "help" it works fine.

Answer (score 35):

> PTY allocation request failed on channel 0

There is a limit of 256 pseudo terminals on a system.  Maybe you have an application that is leaking pseudo terminals.  Use

```
lsof /dev/pts/*
```

to see what processes have open pseudo-terminals

> shell request failed on channel 0

I was getting this error (without PTY allocation error).  It turns out that one of my applications (QtCreator 3.0.?) was leaking Zombie processes.  Other users were able to log in so I might have been hitting my per user process quota (if there is such a thing).  I've updated to QtCreator 3.3.  So far so good.

Comment: How to check that on windows, my remote machine is linux however I connect to this remote machine using ssh on a Windows computer using GitBash.
How to do this command on Windows

Comment: The OP said they are on MacOS. Is this solution intended to work on MacOS? When I tried it (MacOS 10.15.5), I got: `lsof: status error on /dev/pts/*: No such file or directory`.

Comment: On which system, client or server? It's not clear from the answer.

Answer (score 32):

unmount and mount `/dev/pts` worked for me

```
umount /dev/pts

mount devpts /dev/pts -t devpts
```

Reference: http://www.iitk.ac.in/LDP/LDP/lfs/5.0/html/chapter06/proc.html

Comment: When able to login via ssh, "umount" will not work because the device is in use.

Comment: I was playing around with namespaces and I wanted to ssh into a chroot jail running in a separate namespace. I was getting the same error, but `mount devpts /dev/pts -t devpts` did the trick for me.

Comment: Add that this is *on the server*, not in the client

Answer (score 17):

I had the exact same error trying to connect via ssh to my server. As I can see you're using a server provided by Hetzner connecting to it on port 22:

> debug1: Connecting to xxx.your-server.de [188.40.3.15] port 22.

The offical wiki/documention from [Hetzner](https://wiki.hetzner.de/index.php/KonsoleH:Sicherheit_(SSL,_FTPS,_SFTP,_usw.)/en) says:

> Protocol for encrypted remote diagnostics for servers/computers(consoles). The SSH port to be used is 222.

So you have to connect via port 222:

```
ssh -p 222 username@my-server.de
```

Comment: this is unrelated to a PTY allocation error

Comment: Not even closely related to the question ^^

Comment: It is not related to the error, but the same error leads me to this question and changing the port to 222 solved my error. So it is related in a way that the error message might be misleading for the connection you are trying to establish

Answer (score 10):

`shell request failed on channel 0`

mean you don't have shell or remote commands access, fix your user permission on server to have shell access or if you just want tunneling use `-N` and `-T` options

Comment: would be awesome an example .. :D

Comment: or you can just run a command remotely like `ssh user@hostname uptime` then you do not use a shell.

Comment: Or you may be able to use sftp rather than ssh, if you cannot add shell or remote command access to the server.

Answer (score 9):

I solved a similar problem with one of our users who was used only for ssh port forwarding so he don't need to have access to PTY and it was prohibited in .ssh/authorized_keys file:

```
no-pty ssh-rsa AAA...nUB9 someuser
```

So when you tried to log in to this user, only message

```
PTY allocation request failed on channel 0
```

was returned. So check your user's authorized_keys file.

Comment: Right ! in my `authorized_keys` i had a command that didn't exists: `command=/path/to/notexistingfile, ssh-rsa ....`

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

```
vi /etc/security/limits.d/20-nproc.conf
*          soft    nproc     4096   # change to 65535 
root       soft    nproc     unlimited
```

Comment: This is what it was for me. I had just set some values in security/limits.conf that I normally set on users, but somehow my low value was now too low. Apparently a 50 process limit isn't enough anymore. Something must be starting a bunch of processes on login. Linux is getting bloated!

Answer (score 7):

If you are trying to test your github ssh key write

`ssh -T git@github.com`

instead of `ssh -t git@github.com`

Comment: Then what? I still get the same "exec request failed on channel 0". What does that mean? What is the expected result from your command?

Answer (score 5):

Just add these lines to your `/etc/mtab` and `/etc/fstab`, and reboot the system.

```
none    /dev/pts    devpts    defaults    0    0
```

Comment: This worked. On a live CD, you can also do: $ mount -t devpts none /target/dev/pts; chroot /target

Comment: if I use Git bash to connect to aws server, and got this problem.
should I modify these files from the main Git bash directory at Program Files?

Comment: Useful tip: you can run a command without logging in and allocating a pty, e.g. `ssh root@example.com '/sbin/reboot'`

Comment: But what does this code do. You should provide an explanation

Comment: We did this operation (change fstab & mtab and reboot) and it worked... for a while. Apparently it was the reboot that resolved the issue, and now our suspicion is that the remote machine is running out of resources.

Comment: [I don't think you should be editing /etc/mtab see this post](https://askubuntu.com/a/754275/323009).

Answer (score 4):

just found out, what was the problem in my case (provider strato):
I had the same problem with output "shell request failed on channel 0" in the end.

I have to use the master password with the web-domain name as login. (In German
www.wunschname.de, where wunschname is your web-address.)

A ssh login with sftp-user names and the corresponding passwords is without success. (Although scp and sftp works with these sftp users!)

Answer (score 3):

It's an old question, but if someone gets here like me...

This might be result of a wrong date in the server. If you are working with an embedded system this might be the cause... So check your date:

```
$ date
```

Answer (score 3):

I also faced the same issue. Just restarting my servers solved the issue.

Answer (score 3):

If you come to this Q&A for `sftp` while `ssh` is working, and you are getting:

```
subsystem request failed on channel 0
```

make sure `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` contains the following line(s):

```
# override default of no subsystems
Subsystem       sftp    /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server
```

They are there by default, but might have been removed for hardening purposes.

Answer (score 2):

rebooting the instance from AWS console worked for me. There was a service that was leaking file connections that `lsof` helped find.

Answer (score 2):

This is what which helped me from the various answers provided.

- Try logging in as root, that will get you in most of the times
- Try logging in as a different user, it successful, it means that the problem is with a specific account & it implies that there are some process(es) already started by the problematic account which are consuming resources preventing login(most likely no of processes)
- Increase the limit in /etc/security/limits.d/20-nproc.conf as mentioned by xmduhan above
- Try to ssh again, it should work

Answer (score 2):

In my case, my sshd_config contained the value

PermitTTY No

I have to change this to

PermitTTY yes

To log in, I used
ssh user@address /bin/bash -i

This gives me a shell without PTY.
I then used sed to edit the file:

sed -e '/PermitTTY.*/PermitTTY yes/' < /etc/ssh/sshd_config > sshd_new

Then

sudo -S cp sshd_new /etc/ssh/sshd_config

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this error while using my git bash. I was able to solve this by re-installing git for windows. More details in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56264790/3885927).

Answer (score 1):

This was happening when I was trying to use sudo on  `ssh -t git@github.com` after adding my local user's public key to github

Just a head's up to the google happy people like me

Comment: Omg. Wasted so much time on this. I was using an "Administrator" powershell instance. Closed and used a non-elevated shell, and it worked fine. Ty

Answer (score 1):

Just rebooting a AWS instance works for me to clear the error `shell request failed on channel 0`

Answer (score 0):

remounting /dev/pts works for me. you can do this remotely via ssh if you run ssh like this against the affected machine. ssh doesn't request a tty when running commands like this and therefore this will allow you to remount /dev/pts remotely

ssh user@host -- 'mount -o remount,rw /dev/pts'

Comment: Gives me back `mount: only root can use "--options" option`. Well, I don't have `root` previlege.

Answer (score 0):

I occasionally see this when spinning up a VM.  Our automation system starts applying updates, so depending on timing can hit an update to critical packages.

Upshot - this might happen if ssh or other related packages are being updated on the destination machine.

Answer (score 0):

Should a person find themselves reading this QA while they are trying to `ssh` into a NetGear ReadyNAS device, be sure that the "rsync only" checkbox is **un**checked in the dialog box for the ssh service in the admin interface.

Answer (score 0):

As you already found the -T flag that create a PTY, I will just respond to the second part:

> shell request failed on channel 0

You should pass a command:

```
ssh username@my-server.de -p 22 help
```

After reading back the manual here: https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/managing/cli/, I find it not really clear that it would not work without a command. But as stated by @U.V., the ssh interface is not a console interface, rather a connection utility. So you need to pass a command...

If someone from the "jenkins" team pass accross this post, it would be great that if we pass no command, the help would show up :-)

Answer (score -2):

try with option -NT

ssh -NT ...

Comment: Why? Can you add an explanation for long term value, and helpfulness to future visitors who may run into similar issues?

Comment: this worked for me in testing with github to check if my RSA key worked

Comment: -N      Do not execute a remote command.  This is useful for just forwarding ports.