# ssh through container causes stdin: is not a tty

Tags: docker

After I have updated OS X to MacOS Sierra, if I try to ssh through a local container, I get this error:

```
~ ssh root@192.168.1.34 -p 220
PTY allocation request failed on channel 0
Welcome to Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.19.0-43-generic x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/

The programs included with the Ubuntu system are free software;
the exact distribution terms for each program are described in the
individual files in /usr/share/doc/*/copyright.

Ubuntu comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by
applicable law.

stdin: is not a tty
```

Any idea?

```
~ docker version
Client:
 Version:      1.12.3-rc1
 API version:  1.24
 Go version:   go1.6.3
 Git commit:   bad4d12
 Built:        Tue Oct 25 08:19:41 2016
 OS/Arch:      darwin/amd64
 Experimental: true

Server:
 Version:      1.12.3-rc1
 API version:  1.24
 Go version:   go1.6.3
 Git commit:   bad4d12
 Built:        Tue Oct 25 08:19:41 2016
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
 Experimental: true
```

However, I can exec like this:

```
docker exec -it trackware-web bash
```

Comment: The answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27021641/how-to-fix-request-failed-on-channel-0) might be helpful. [This question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48527/ssh-inside-ssh-fails-with-stdin-is-not-a-tty) is a little old but may also be related.

Comment: ssh to a docker container is in itself smelly unless your container is an ssh server. You should do the exec as you suggested yourself. 
Have you tried "ssh -t -t root@192.168.1.34 -p 220"?

Comment: I am sorry, this is an old question relatively, however, yes, I use exec instead of ssh, and things are fine :) thanks