# Powershell Invoke-Command SSH pem key connection Error: subsystem request failed on channel 0

Tags: .net, powershell, ps1

I am new to Powershell scripting. Currently, I am trying to send a command via SSH with a PEM private key for authentication. I am able to connect via SSH fine with this key.

However, when I tried to use the `Invoke-Command` provided by Powershell with the below command

```
Invoke-Command -HostName 'root@192.168.0.2' -KeyFilePath key.pem -ScriptBlock { ls }
```

I keep getting this error:

```
subsystem request failed on channel 0
```

From what I have searched, this error is mainly caused by no authentication or invalid command. However, I am able to log in via SSH (key should be correct) and the remote program is running Linux (`ls` command should be acceptable?). Any help on this error would be appreciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix request failed on channel 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27021641/how-to-fix-request-failed-on-channel-0)

Comment: Sounds like an sshd problem, check the Linux server logs