# Pushing to a remote GitHub repository

Tags: git, ssh, push

My professor wants us to use his github repository for his course. I created the ssh key, I added the private key to ssh-agent and given the public key to the professor.
After I created the project folder and run the following steps:

```
git init
git add *
git commit -m "Initial commit"
git remote add origin git@github.com:prof_username/repo_name.git
git push -u origin master
```

I get a permission denied (error 403). I tried both ssh and https url. What's the problem?

Comment: Surely you didn't literally use `git@github.com:prof_username/repo_name.git`?

Comment: @Biffen I'd hope that was just to hide the actual user/repo name.

Comment: @Biffen as Trengot said, i changed the real user/repo name for privacy.

Comment: @retrobitguy I assumed as much: It was a bit of a shot in the dark. Is there any more output? It's hard to help without more info, other than referring to https://help.github.com.

Comment: @Biffen The message when i do the push is: "ERROR: Permission to prof_username/repo_name.git denied to myusername. fatal: Could not read from remote repository. Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.". I can clone the repo, but seems i can't push on it. My professor needs to do something to fix that?

Comment: @retrobitguy ‘*make sure you have the correct access rights*’ seems key here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already have a repository, you don't have to initialise it; Just clone it to your local computer:

```
git clone git@github.com:prof_username/repo_name.git
```

And you can set your upstream with:

```
git branch -u origin/my_branch
```

[Edit] ...and check what key is used:

```
ssh -vvv git@github.com
```

Comment: You are right, i don't need to initialize the repo. But the problem persist.
the message when i do the push is:
ERROR: Permission to prof_username/repo_name.git denied to myusername.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.

Comment: @retrobitguy Did you have any problem cloning the repository? Or is it only when you try to push? Maybe take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13509293/git-fatal-could-not-read-from-remote-repository/20714212#20714212

Comment: @LarsNielsen No problem with the cloning. My problem is only with the push. I will look the link. Thanks

Comment: @LarsNielsen Thank you! The solution was in this link :) The problem was that git was using another ssh key, so i created a new rule in the `~/.ssh/config` where i specified the correct key to use with that specific repository.