# Push failed in clion

Tags: git, github, clion

I make c++ project and add it to GitHub but when I try to push I get that error what is the problem here?

**Note: I create the repo in GitHub first then push to it.

but if I choose share to GitHub at first everything works very well.

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13509293/git-fatal-could-not-read-from-remote-repository

Comment: I have tried it a lot but same problem.