# CentOS: Git: "fatal: could not read from the remote repository"

Tags: linux, git, centos

( I have already read through this, and several other posts, thoroughly [git: fatal: Could not read from remote repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13509293/git-fatal-could-not-read-from-remote-repository) )

I'm using my own server as a git server. I set it up according to several guides. Everything is fine except any operation that read or writes to the remote git repository.

**Problem:**

When I try to do anything that interacts with the remote server that I have set up, I get:

> fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository
> exists.

in windows shell. In Cygwin it just hangs.

**Quick Background:**

I'm using CentOS 7 as the server and Windows 10 as the client.

On the server:

- I made a new user 'git'
- mkdir /home/git/myproject.git
- git init --bare
- opened up necessary ports 9418, 22, & 443 using:

  "firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port=22/tcp" and

  "firewall-cmd --reload"

On the client:

- created a folder, created a text file with some text, ran 'git init', 'git add .'
- setup rsa keys according to several guides

**What Works:**

I can ssh into the server fine with windows shell, cygwin and puTTy. The folder /home/git/mproject.git exists. git has been working fine locally using either windows shell or Cygwin.

**Attempted solutions:**

I've tried:

```
chmod 600 pyproject.git
chmod 700 pyproject.git
chmod 777 pyproject.git
git remote add origin git@my-site.com:/home/git/myproject.git
git remote add origin git@my-site:/home/git/myproject.git
git remote add origin ssh://git@my-site.com/home/git/myproject.git
git remote add origin ssh://git@my-site.com/repo-<wbr< a="">>/home/git/myproject.git..git
git remote add origin ssh://git@my-site.com/repo-<wbr< a="">>/home/git/myproject.git
git remote add origin git@my-site.com:/home/git/myproject.git
git clone git@my-site.com:/home/git/myproject.git
git remote add origin https://git@my-site.com/home/git/myproject.git
git clone ssh://git@my-site.com/home/git/myproject.git
git clone ssh://git@my-site.com/myproject.git
git clone https://git@my-site.com:myproject.git
git clone ssh://git@my-site.com/home/git/myproject.git
git clone git@my-site.com/home/git/myproject.git
git clone git@my-site.com:/home/git/myproject.git
git clone git@my-site.com/myproject.git
```

I can log into the server with ssh git@my-site.com just fine. I can also navigate to the /home/git/myproject.git folder. The ports are open. What else could be wrong?

Comment: Are user "git" able to clone the repo locally on the server?

Comment: yes. (I just tested it after you posted this)

Comment: Can you clone the repo locally on the server as another user with `git clone ssh://git@my-site.com/home/git/myproject.git`?

Comment: yes, after being asked for 'git's password

Comment: This is probably far-fetched, can you clone any other remote repo using `ssh:` from your client? To rule out problems with ssh locally you can try cloning using `http:` or `git:`.

Comment: Can you elaborate? I don't have any other repos set up. I can clone locally on the server. I can't clone remotely. I can do everything fine locally on either machine. It's when I try to do anything with git remotely that I have problems. I can even copy folders back and forth remotely without issue. I was thinking it was a permissions or syntax issue but I tried many different possibilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem *seems* to have been that the client and the server were using versions of git that were very different. The client was using 1.9 I believe, and the server was using 2.6. Not only that, the versions of git differed depending on the whether I was using windows terminal or Cygwin.

Now, after removing old versions and updating git, commands like:

```
git remote add origin git@mysite.com:/home/git/myproject.git
git push origin master
```

work correctly.