# Git push: "ERROR: Repository not found' - "fatal: Could not read from remote repository"

Tags: github, ssh-keys, git-push, droplet

### In short

**Goal:** to perform one successful git push using ssh instead of https.

**Problem:** "ERROR: Repository not found. Fatal: Could not read from remote repository".

### Step-by-step background

I’m working with an Ubuntu remote server (a droplet by DigitalOcean) and a Github account. I created an ssh public key on my Ubuntu remote server and used it to create a new ssh key on Github. Then I changed my remote’s URL from https to ssh with the git remote set-url command:

```
git remote set-url origin git@github.com:[username]/[repository].git
```

Following that, I tested if things worked:

```
root@[DropletName]:/srv/test_git_folder# ssh -T git@github.com
The authenticity of host 'github.com (140.87.148.9)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is SHA365:mVhbp6kXUbJWCl7E1IGOCspRamTxdCARLviWk6F5SY9.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added 'github.com,140.87.148.9' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
Hi [Username]! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```

At this point I tried to create a short text file...

```
root@[DropletName]:/srv/test_git_folder# nano testfile2.txt
[nano text editor appears; I input "Hello world!", save and close]
```

...and push it to github

```
root@[DropletName]:/srv/test_git_folder# git add *
root@[DropletName]:/srv/test_git_folder# git commit -m "test push"
[master 5b6bcb0] test push
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 testfile2.txt
```

But in the end I got an error message:

```
root@[DropletName]:/srv/test_git_folder# git push –u origin master

ERROR: Repository not found.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

How can I fix that?

(I've been unsuccessfully looking at a some similar questions, including the following: 
- [Git : Could not read from remote repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51133215/git-could-not-read-from-remote-repository)
- [CentOS: Git: "fatal: could not read from the remote repository"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31885482/centos-git-fatal-could-not-read-from-the-remote-repository)
- [git push to remote repository "Could not read from remote repository"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16118797/git-push-to-remote-repository-could-not-read-from-remote-repository))

Answer (score -1):

First, make sure the remote repository does exist and has been created on GitHub first.
See if you can browse the page at https://github.com/[username]/[repository]

Then type `git remote -v` in `/srv/test_git_folder` to check the URL is the correct one (same case, since it is case sensitive)