# How to transfer git repo from Bitbucket to Github in Android Studio?

Tags: android, git, android-studio, github, bitbucket

So I have an Android Studio project that I have on Bitbucket that I'm having trouble moving to Github. So far I've imported the project to Github using its import feature and changed the origin using "git remote set-url". Now every time I try to push & commit using Android Studio I get the error "fatal: Could not read from repository". Also I don't know if it has anything to do with the problem but I have tried to change the SSH executable from built-in to native.

Edit: To clarify, the problem I'm having is committing and pushing using Android Studio. Everything works fine if I use git commands but when I use the Android Studio interface the "fatal: Could not read from repository" error pops up.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [git: fatal: Could not read from remote repository](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13509293/git-fatal-could-not-read-from-remote-repository)

Comment: If the above link doesn't solve your problem, please update your question with a description of what you tried and what the results were.

Comment: Is the GitHub project empty or does it have content?

Comment: Are you using the HTTPS or SSH addresses to your repos?

Comment: The GitHub project has all the contents of the Bitbucket project minus one or two commits, and I'm using ssh addresses

Comment: See my answer about using multiple remotes.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest creating separate remotes rather than changing the URL for `origin`. For example, you can do

```
git remote add bitbucket <URL for BitBucket repo>
git remote add github <URL for GitHub Repo>
```

Now you can pull and push from each remote as you wish. For example

```
git checkout master
git pull bitbucket master
git push github master
```