# git clone --recursive fails

Tags: git

I've encountered a strange issue while trying to recursively clone a git repository:

```
# git clone --recursive git@github.com:eteran/edb-debugger.git
Initialized empty Git repository in /edb-debugger/.git/
The authenticity of host 'github.com (192.30.253.113)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is 16:27:ac:a5:76:28:2d:36:63:1b:56:4d:eb:df:a6:48.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added 'github.com,192.30.253.113' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Trying on another machine returned a different result:

```
$ git clone --recursive git@github.com:eteran/edb-debugger.git
Cloning into 'edb-debugger'...
Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '192.30.253.112' to the list of known hosts.
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I'm not sure what's going on with the inconsistent errors, or why this suddenly started happening when it was working perfectly fine shortly before. There are two ( separate ) other questions ( [¹](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13509293/git-fatal-could-not-read-from-remote-repository)[₂](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15240815/git-fatal-the-remote-end-hung-up-unexpectedly)  ) which mention each error, however, this is encapsulates both errors in one unrelated issue.

Any clue what the problem might be?

Comment: Maybe you install a software that add a new SSH key in your config?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can resolve this in 2 ways:

Either, Create ssh-key and add the public key of both computers in the github account. After that this command will work

```
 git clone --recursive git@github.com:eteran/edb-debugger.git
```

Or, clone using https. This will prompt for credentials enter the credentials and it will be cloned

```
git clone --recursive https://github.com/eteran/edb-debugger.git
```

In case you are having problem with already created ssh keys use this command to see if your ssh key is loaded properly and your public key is added properly in your github account. To see your loaded key:

```
ssh-add -l
```

It should list your key like this:

```
2048 SHA256:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX /Users/<username>/.ssh/id_rsa (RSA)
```

Comment: The first option really isn't ideal since I use hundreds of machines; the second option seemed to have worked without prompting for any credentials — so I'd say problem solved. Thanks!

Comment: Great! You're welcome :). It didn't ask for credentials because its a public repository.

Answer (score 4):

An other easy solution instead of messing with keys...

#### To force https instead of git

```
git config --global url."https://github.com/".insteadOf git@github.com:
git config --global url."https://".insteadOf git://
```

#### To force git instead of https

```
git config --global url."git@github.com:".insteadOf https://github.com/
git config --global url."git://".insteadOf https://
```

Answer (score 0):

```
git clone --recursive https://github.com/Xvirus0/Xvirus-Tools.git
<Control> <pannel> ===GitHubLoadFiles
git clone --recursive https://github.com/Xvirus0/Xvirus-Tools.gitgit clone --recursive https://github.com/Xvirus0/Xvirus-Tools.gitgit clone --recursive https://github.com/Xvirus0/Xvirus-Tools.git
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: To passers by: I'm not sure what that repo is supposed to do, and it has nothing to do with the question. Please use caution.