# error while pushing to GitHub

Tags: android, git, github

i want to commit changes to GitHub 
i can do it with GitHub desktop but i get this error when i try with android studio commit changes button :
"Failed with error: fatal: unable to access 'https://github. ... .git/': The requested URL returned error: 403"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [git: fatal: Could not read from remote repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13509293/git-fatal-could-not-read-from-remote-repository)

Comment: you are using https, so check username/password and the link.

Answer (score 0):

You need to first find the correct SSH/ HTTP address to the repository that you would like to commit to then you can run this command in your terminal:

**git remote add origin [remote repository URL]**

once connected, you should be able to commit the changes.