# ssh: connect to host gitlab.kpit.com port 22: Connection refused fatal: Could not read from remote repository

Tags: git, jenkins, gitlab, devops

While I'm pushing the project from my local box to my repository using `git push -u origin master` command, it shows the connection refused error.

My **branch** is `master` and **remote** is `origin`

Comment: Have you added your **PUBLIC SSH key** to your repository **SSH keys** list?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [git: fatal: Could not read from remote repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13509293/git-fatal-could-not-read-from-remote-repository)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you cannot connect to the remote host via SSH while trying to push your changes over SSH.

You can try to add verbosity to the output with:

```
GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -vvv" git push -u origin master
```

and see what happens

Common issues:
 - SSH is firewalled to certain IP addresses on the remote host
 - SSH server is running on non-default port

Notice: I assumed, that you're using self-hosted GitLab installation