# Multiaccount codecommit setup aws

Tags: aws-codecommit

How to set up multiple account code commit?
I am able to set for the only single user.

I am getting below error

> Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository
>   exists

Comment: Possible duplicate of [git: fatal: Could not read from remote repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13509293/git-fatal-could-not-read-from-remote-repository)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to hear about that. Can you describe more about the workflow you're trying to achieve through multi account access?

In the meantime, here's a link that explains how to achieve cross account access to CodeCommit if that helps: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/userguide/cross-account.html