# Local git clone doesn't work on particular machine

Tags: windows, git

I want to clone one **local** repository into another one on the same machine:

```
C:\Projects\b> git clone C:\Projects\a  .
```

It works for one Windows machine but doesn't for another. It shows:

```
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

File/directory permissions seems to be OK.

One more thing: in git-bash for windows it works OK, but I need to do it in git-cmd because of further integration into CI-build-service.

Could you suggest something to diagnose/resolve this issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [git: fatal: Could not read from remote repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13509293/git-fatal-could-not-read-from-remote-repository)

Comment: It this question they are talking about remote repositories and user credentials, but I want to clone local git repo in a sibling folder.

Comment: do `git --git-dir C:\Projects\a\.git log` and like work?

Comment: @max630 this command works fine