# git@github.com: Permission denied_publickey fatal: Could not read from remote repositoryqq

Tags: git, github, git-push

Made such a sequance of commands:

```
eval `ssh-agent -s`
Agent pid 1287

ssh-add D:\\Programming\\Python\\python_folder_key

git remote -v
origin  git@github.com:devmafia/Python_Django_Udemy.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:devmafia/Python_Django_Udemy.git (push)

git push origin master

git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Don't really understand what's wrong in my sequence:

Comment: similar SO question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13509293/git-fatal-could-not-read-from-remote-repository

Comment: Have you uploaded `D:\\Programming\\Python\\python_folder_key.pub` to your account (`devmafia`) at github.com?

Comment: Thanks! now I added it to the folder where I wanted to push, I just didn't do it before, everything works.

Comment: This is how Github describes this in their docs: [Adding a new SSH key to your GitHub account](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account)

Comment: Yes, it does, thanks!