# Github authentication error when trying to push on command line (SSH key added in Github)

Tags: authentication, github, ssh, push

I have generated and added my SSH key into Github.

Now I'm trying to write a script which generates a new private repository in Github and upload intiial files. User will be prompted for the name of the new repository.

The code that I have is given below. The problem is that when trying to push files into Github I get the following error

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname github.com:rongardF: Name or service not known
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Why do I get this error? Is there anything else that I have to do?

The code:

```
@echo off
set /p name="Enter new project name: "

touch README.md
touch .gitignore
echo __Previews>>.gitignore
echo History>>.gitignore
echo Project Outputs *>>.gitignore
echo * Logs *>>.gitignore

git config --global user.email "r****n@gmail.com"
git config --global user.name "R** F****"

curl -u r***F:p*****d https://api.github.com/user/repos -d "{\"name\":\"%name%\",\"private\":true}"

git init
git add .
git commit -m "Initial commit"
git remote add origin git@github.com:r***F/%name%.git
git push -u origin master
```

NB: The names obviously don't include "*" symbol, this is just for blurring out my details.

Comment: Have you seen this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13509293/git-fatal-could-not-read-from-remote-repository

Comment: @ron Check also https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_repo_create

Answer (score 0):

```
git remote add origin git@github.com:r***F/%name%.git
```

For testing, you can check if this syntax would work in your case

```
git remote add origin ssh://git@github.com/r***F/%name%.git
```

Check also if a simple `ssh -Tv git@github.com` works (meaning if it display a Welcome message at the end)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestion @VonC

I got it to work by adding the following line before the push command:

```
git remote set-url origin https://github.com/r****F/%name%.git
```

Not sure why, but this works. So the snippet of the final code is:

```
...
...
git init
git add .
git commit -m "Initial commit"
git remote add origin git@github.com:r****dF/%name%.git
git remote set-url origin https://github.com/r****F/%name%.git
git push -u origin master
```

Comment: OK, but that bypass completely ssh.

Comment: okay, but I don't get how I can the access and create repositories in my github account?

Comment: If you have added the the (public) SSH key and if `ssh -Tv git@github.com` works (meaning, if it displays a welcome message), it will be able to push to your repository.