# Suddenly started to receive ssh_exchange_identification error using git/bitbucket

Tags: git, ssh, bitbucket

Nothing was changed in the system.
I work as usually.
And usually there was no any problems with pull/push.
I have access on bitbucket, if I visit it via the browser.

And now when I try to push or pull from bitbucket repository, I get error:

```
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
```

Below is a command with verbose output, but I cannot understand what is the problem.

Command used for verbose output:
`$ GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -vvv" git pull`

The output:

```
OpenSSH_7.9p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/volk/.ssh/config
debug1: /Users/volk/.ssh/config line 48: Applying options for *
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 48: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "bitbucket.org" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct
debug1: Connecting to bitbucket.org [18.205.93.2] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/volk/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file /Users/volk/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/volk/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/volk/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/volk/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/volk/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/volk/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/volk/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/volk/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/volk/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.9
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
```

Comment: I do not know what has happened, nothing changed, but it now works back again.

Comment: Alright. It was Bitbucket problem. here is more info: https://bitbucket.status.atlassian.com/incidents/jbvzjz4yldss

Answer (score 3):

Got same issue today.

Fixed the issue via add following lines in ssh config(vim ~/.ssh/config)

```
Host bitbucket.org
  AddKeysToAgent yes
  HostName altssh.bitbucket.org
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
  UseKeychain yes
  Port 443
```

Comment: wohoo..this is the only one worked thanks :D

Answer (score 1):

It might be a problem with Bitbucket.

Check Bitbucket status https://bitbucket.status.atlassian.com/history

---

That's what happened to me and the original poster, but I didn't think to check until seeing the comment on the question here.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced a similar issue all of a sudden. I tried of couple of suggestions given in [ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host under Git bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10127818/ssh-exchange-identification-connection-closed-by-remote-host-under-git-bash) but the following one worked for me.

1. Delete ssh folder (`~/.ssh`)
2. Recreate .ssh using ssh-keygen
3. Configure the latest public key
4. Then now try your git commands