# Authenticating heroku commands run from Rails app on heroku server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku

I am writing a script for periodically dumping the database and uploading it to S3

I have this method call utilizes the Heroku gem and that gets called from a rake task at various intervals

```
def dump_database
  Rails.logger.info "Dumping database into temporary file."

  # Stamp the filename
  datestamp = Time.now.strftime("%d-%m-%Y_%H-%M-%S")    

  # Drop it in the db/backups directory temporarily
  file_path = "#{Rails.root}/db/backups/APPNAME_#{Rails.env}_#{datestamp}_dump.sql.gz" 

  # Dump and zip the backup file
  sh "heroku pgbackups:capture --expire -a APPNAME-#{Rails.env}"
  sh "curl -o #{file_path} `heroku pgbackups:url -a APPNAME-#{Rails.env}` | gzip > #{file_path}" 

  return file_path
end
```

Problem is that when I call the

```
sh "heroku pgbackups:capture --expire -a APPNAME-#{Rails.env}"
```

Heroku asks for credentials (email/password) to me entered into the terminal

Cant this be done without entering credentials?

Comment: append rsa key to heroku's account, and use it, then it will not require login/password pair

Comment: rsa? could you give an example

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13355509/heroku-added-ssh-public-key-and-still-getting-permission-denied-publickey-er

Comment: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/keys

Comment: if i understood them correctly, both of those links refer to the case in which one uses heroku commands from their local machine to the heroku server, and not when the app already on heroku uses heroku commands to itself