# OpenShift Git Clone error

Tags: git-clone, openshift

I am a newbie on OpenShift , I have a problem with it ,

When I do

```
rhc app git-clone mynewapp


Your public ssh key must be uploaded to the OpenShift server.  Would you like us to upload it for you? (yes/no) yes

You can enter a name for your key, or leave it blank to use the default name. Using the same name as an existing key will overwrite
the old key.

Since you do not have any keys associated with your OpenShift account,
your new key will be uploaded as the 'default' key

type: ssh-rsa
content:
AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQCuA9kdmq5Pf5JLyHeMpWQ+XYaEzw8UWziUfXohMR8Dt9ZwkIb4WSHLzcGKKpclZvWOi2UZMQCOp8wCij5VS/ps8/3YPQVYyg+GHAAZIr
WsGDnJdpRF/shUnvoPx6XTzzLFHxBOS92LktjvX/T+xqftS6aVugD0cQ0vVkA6e5FwIjwo4JHoJGRFzgdaSbC5nDiHvDX7zhtnQXe1TeTK5nhjDj/uZPaj5h0hRv4Zx0EzfDYu
Uig0GCoFrWsJ9MTw5F7WEeOtPNtp2uFubuDCDpoBtBBDDmL642AY8r9IV4REGSfUDzV+M0Ab33ubRYKmp+ok6MtBrlTKg94PaVvuf2V5
fingerprint: eb:41:87:1b:e8:4e:ec:c0:8d:c8:c6:5e:a2:6a:ad:b4
Uploading key 'default' from /home/toriq/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
Cloning into 'myapp'...
done
```

Suddenly an error appear:

```
Error in git clone - Agent admitted failure to sign using the key.
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Any solution for this ?

Answer (score 4):

It could be similar to this [GitHub help page](https://help.github.com/articles/error-agent-admitted-failure-to-sign):

> For most users, simply running `ssh-add` to load your keys into the SSH agent will fix this issue.

```
$ ssh-add
# Enter passphrase for /home/you/.ssh/id_rsa: [tippy tap]
# Identity added: /home/you/.ssh/id_rsa (/home/you/.ssh/id_rsa)
```

> If your key does not have the default filename, you'll have to pass the path to `ssh-add`:

```
$ ssh-add ~/.ssh/my_other_key
# Enter passphrase for /home/you/.ssh/my_other_key: [tappity tap tap]
# Identity added: /home/you/.ssh/my_other_key (/home/you/.ssh/my_other_key)
```

Comment: Ok , thanks for solution , 
but when I do ssh-add , there is a permission denied problem ti id_rsa.

Comment: @ToriqPriaDhigfora do you own your ~/.ssh directory? Remember, it must have certain right correctly set: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5471139/6309, and none of the parent directories of your `.ssh` must be writable for group or world (so 755 for instance, not 775).

Answer (score 2):

You can install [rhc openshift client tools](https://www.openshift.com/developers/rhc-client-tools-install)

Then run setup which will then upload your ssh keys.

```
rhc setup
```