# How Clone our repo magento-boilerplate use git

Tags: git, github, twitter-bootstrap-3, magento-1.6

please check this

```
git clone git@github.com:webcomm/magento-boilerplate.git defaut .
```

I trying on my folder default but it not work, it give me the following error:

```
git clone git@github.com:webcomm/magento-boilerplate.git
...
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have correct access rights and the repository exists.
```

Comment: It's better to copy and paste the error message, such that everyone can actually read it and such that it is searchable. If anyone searches for the same error message, the person will not find your post. Also, not posting images helps keeping bandwidth small.

Comment: Funnily, just copying+pasting your error would have saved you and us a lot of time ;)

Answer (score 0):

One quick workaround, if you don't want to debug your ssh settings, is to use an  https url

```
git clone https://github.com/webcomm/magento-boilerplate
```

If not, you can see at "[Unable to Git-push master to Github](https://stackoverflow.com/a/922461/6309)" the various points to check to debug an ssh connection, as well as the rights associates with your $HOME/.ssh folder (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5471139/6309)) and the [Github ssh pages](https://help.github.com/categories/56/articles).