# How to symboling link gitosis repo to another place?

Tags: git

I've got the actual code in public facing dir under one user. It's in `/home/user1/public_html/dev`

And for gitosis I had to set another user Git, and gitosis wants it's repos in "`/home/git/repositories/"`

So, from what I read best and easiest is to just symbolink link them. But which dir to which?

When I create new "test" project locally I have .git sub-folder in the "test" folder, but when push it in "`/home/git/repositories/`" it creates test.git folder on the remote server with the contents of the local .git folder, but I don't see the actual files?

So, i'm a bit confused how this works and what I should link. Please note this my first time with git, gitosis and all this, so i'm probably asking something quite stupid but i'm really blocked at this point.

Answer (score 0):

gitosis (which is [obsolete for a few years now: gitolite is much richer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10888358/6309)) works with **[bare repos](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24115534/6309)**: repos without a working tree.

And `/home/user1/public_html/dev` is a repo *with* a working tree.

So you don't (sym)link both together. Not directly.

You can (for instance) set up a post-receive hook (in the bare repo) in order to go to the non-bare repo  and pull: see "[Gitosis post-receive hook to deploy repository getting public key errors](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5470680/6309)".
You have a much [more complete hook script in this blog post](http://www.sparkhost.co/clients/knowledgebase/140/Using-Gitosis-to-securely-Deploy-a-Website-with-version-control-based-on-the-GitHub-Flow.html).

But the point is: both repos are independent, and acting on one (pushing to a bare repo) will have an effect on the other through a hook.

Comment: Hey, just started looking into it. Seems like gitolite also has it's own dir to store the repos? Is sm linking easier there though?
Or I shoud look into other options. Infact I need to provide secure access to just 1 person right now. But will prefer he doesn't have shell access.

Comment: "But will prefer he doesn't have shell access" that is exactly what gitolite does.